# Sorting an Array of Pointers to Structs in C - Merge Sort Not Working As Expected

Tags: c, math

I'm working on a C program that involves sorting an array of pointers to structs using merge sort. The program manages a binary search tree of customers, and I want to sort the customers based on their loyalty points.

The issue is that the sorting process is not producing the expected results. The printing of customers using the in-order function is correct, but the sorted array appears to be incorrect.

I have provided the relvant sections of the code.

```
int main(void){
    tree_node *my_root = NULL;
    int num_operations;
   
    printf("Enter # of operations: "); // For testing purposes, remove after completion(Remove when submitting)
    scanf("%d", &num_operations);

    for(int i=0; i< num_operations; i++){
        char operation[20];
        char name[MAXLEN + 1];
        int points;
        tree_node *recent_customer = NULL;

        scanf("%s", operation);

        if(strcmp(operation, "add") == 0){
            scanf("%s %d", name, &points);
            // Checking if the customer already exists
            searchResult *result = search(my_root, name);
            if(result!=NULL && result->tPtr!= NULL){
                result->tPtr->cPtr->points += points; // If customer exists then you update the points
                printf("%s %d\n", result->tPtr->cPtr->name, result->tPtr->cPtr->points); //Printing customer if they exist
                free(result); // Free searchResult after usage
            }else{
                customer *new_customer = (customer *)malloc(sizeof(customer));
                if(new_customer == NULL){
                    fprintf(stderr,"Memory Allocation Failed\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                recent_customer = (tree_node*)malloc(sizeof(tree_node));
                 
                //Populating customer 
                strncpy(new_customer->name, name, MAXLEN);
                new_customer->points = points;

                //Adding customer to tree
                tree_node *temp_node = create_node(new_customer);
                my_root = insert(my_root, temp_node);

                recent_customer ->cPtr = new_customer;
                
                //Reallocate memory for new customers
                customers = (customer **)realloc(customers, (num_customers + 1)  * sizeof(customer*));
                if(customers == NULL){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Memory Allocation failed");
                    exit(1);
                }
                //Store the customer pointer in array
                customers[num_customers] = new_customer;
                num_customers++;

                printf("%s %d\n", recent_customer->cPtr->name, recent_customer->cPtr->points);
            }
        }else if(strcmp(operation, "sub") == 0){
            char customer_name[MAXLEN + 1];
            int subtractPoints;

            //Taking input
            scanf("%s %d" ,customer_name, &subtractPoints);

            //Searching for customer
            searchResult *result = search(my_root, customer_name);

            if(result!=NULL && result->tPtr !=NULL){
                //Subtract Points
                if(subtractPoints >= result->tPtr->cPtr->points){
                    result->tPtr->cPtr->points = 0;
                    printf("%s %d\n", result->tPtr->cPtr->name,result->tPtr->cPtr->points);
                }else{
                    result->tPtr->cPtr->points -= subtractPoints;
                    //Update points in the customer array
                    for(int i=0; i<num_customers; i++){
                        if(customers[i]==result->tPtr->cPtr){
                            customers[i]->points = result->tPtr->cPtr->points;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    printf("%s %d\n", result->tPtr->cPtr->name, result->tPtr->cPtr->points);
                }
                free(result);
            }else{
                printf("%s not found\n", customer_name);
            }       
        }else if(strcmp(operation, "search") == 0){
            scanf("%s", name);

            printf("Searching for customer:\n"); //Debugging purposes
            searchResult *result = search(my_root, name);

            if(result!=NULL && result->tPtr!=NULL){
                printf("%s %d %d\n", result->tPtr->cPtr->name, result->points, result->depth); //Prints out name, loyalty points and depth
                free(result);
            }else{
                printf("%s not found\n", name);
                free(result); // Free searchResult after usage
            }

        }else if(strcmp(operation, "del") == 0){
            char name[MAXLEN + 1];
            scanf("%s", name);

            // Searching for customer
            searchResult *result = search(my_root, name);

            if (result != NULL && result->tPtr != NULL) {
                // Customer found, proceed with deletion
                my_root = delete(my_root, name);
                printf("%s deleted\n", name);

                // Remove the customer pointer from the array
                for (int i = 0; i < num_customers; i++) {
                    if (customers[i] == result->tPtr->cPtr) {
                        // Shift remaining elements to fill the gap
                        for (int j = i; j < num_customers - 1; j++) {
                            customers[j] = customers[j + 1];
                        }
                        num_customers--;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                free(result);
            } else {
                // Customer not found
                printf("%s not found\n", name);
                free(result);
            }
        }else if(strcmp(operation, "count_smaller") == 0){
            char name[MAXLEN + 1];
            scanf("%s", name);
            int count = count_smaller(my_root, name);
            printf("%d\n", count);
        }
    }
    printf("Inorder traversal of the final tree:\n");
    inorder(my_root);
    
    printf("Sorted Array based on points\n");
    
    mergeSort(customers, 0 , (num_customers -1 ));
    
    for(int i = 0; i<num_customers;i++){
        printf("Name: %s  Points: %d\n", customers[i]->name, customers[i]->points);
    }
    
    for(int i =0; i<num_customers; i++){
        free(customers[i]);
    }
    free(customers);
    
    
}
```

```
int compareByPoints(const customer *customer1, const customer *customer2) {
    return customer2->points - customer1->points;
}
```

```
//Merge Sort
void mergeSort(customer **arr, int left, int right){
    if(left < right){
        int mid = left + (right - left)/2;
        mergeSort(arr, left, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, right);
        merge(arr,left, mid, right);
    }
}
//Merge
void merge(customer **arr, int left, int mid, int right){
    int sizeL = (mid - left) + 1;
    int sizeR = (right -  mid);

    customer **leftArray = (customer**)malloc(sizeL * sizeof(customer*));
    customer **rightArray = (customer**)malloc(sizeR * sizeof(customer*));

    for(int i =0; i<sizeL; i++){
        leftArray[i] = arr[left + i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<sizeR; i++){
        rightArray[i] = arr[mid + 1 + i];
    }
    int i, j=0;
    int k = left;

    while(i < sizeL && j < sizeR){
        if(compareByPoints(leftArray[i], rightArray[j]) >= 0){
            arr[k] = leftArray[i];
            i++;
        }else{
            arr[k] = rightArray[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i<sizeL){
        arr[k] = leftArray[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<sizeR){
        arr[k] = rightArray[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    free(leftArray);
    free(rightArray);

}
```

I have already added debug statements to the compareByPoints function, and it is returning the expected values. However, the sorting is not working as intended.

Could someone please review the code and provide insights into why the sorting might not be working correctly? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.